# Ember.js RC1 - controller 'needs' another that does not yet exist

Tags: ember.js

My routing structure:

```
App.ready = function() {
    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('contacts', function() {
            this.resource('contact', function() {
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now in my `contactsController` I respond to and `add` action that transitions to the contact route.  I would then like to call the `add` method on my `contactController`.

I have placed the `needs: ['contact']` on my `ContactController` but then I get this message:

```
<App.ContactsController:ember197> needs controller:contact but it does not exist
```

When I use `controllerFor` (which *is* deprecated) I also get an error:

```
this.controllerFor('contact').add();
```

So Ember.js RC1 appears to only create the controllers (and other related instances) once one actually transitions to the appropriate route.

Is there a way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So Ember.js RC1 appears to only create the controllers (and other related instances) once one actually transitions to the appropriate route.

Interesting - I had thought ember generated controllers earlier but guess not.

> Is there a way around this?

Workaround is to define App.ContactController manually. Something like this will work:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('contacts', function() {
        this.resource('contact', function() {
        });
    });
});

App.ContactController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  add: function() {
    alert('App.ContactController.add() was called!');
  }
});

App.ContactsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['contact'],
  add: function() {
    this.get('controllers.contact').add();
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/osapal/1/edit

Comment: OK, I see what I did wrong.  For the contact I had a `ContactIndexController` since I was also playing around with a resource nested under contact.  In this case I needed to `needs: ['contactIndex']`.  I also had a `needs: ['contacts']` in the `ContactController` so the controllers do not seem to have to be instantiated when the `needs` is processed.  The naming conventions are a bit confusing with the `Index` suffix but not a train smash.  Once I have a better grasp of Ember it'll probably make sense.